# TERADATA: WHILE LOOP works as SELECT but not in my SPROC

Tags: sql, arrays, variables, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I created the following stored procedure in teradata to start with current run day and pull all invoices within that particular week. Then continue going back for 52 weeks, and insert the records into my holder table.

However I can run the SELECT fine without the WHILE loop. But when I create a stored procedure of this successfully and run I receiving the following message:

> OUTLETLOOPMG:An owner referenced by user does not have SELECT access to CORP_INVOICE_VIEWS.INVOICE_CORP.Ownrshp_ID

Which I don't understand being the select works fine without the loop.

So two question:

1. What's up with that error?
2. Based off logic I describe in initial paragraph, does my WHILE loop achieve this?

Code:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE OutletLoopMG()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE iVAR INT DEFAULT 52;
    DECLARE dVAR DATE DEFAULT current_date;

    --SET iVAR = 52;
    --SET dVAR = current_date;

    WHILE  iVAR > 0
    DO
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dlccc_cust_cntc_cntr_lab.OutletHolder
            SELECT 
                invcorp.OWNRSHP_ID, invcorp.BTLR_DLVR_PNT_NO,
                snap.btlr_branch_nm, snap.dlvr_pnt_nm,
                invcorp.inv_no, invcorp.inv_dt,
                cal.week_of_year, cal.year_of_calendar
            FROM
                corp_invoice_VIEWS.invoice_corp invcorp
            LEFT JOIN
                CHR_VIEWS.DPT_SNAPSHOT_SELECT snap ON invcorp.BTLR_DLVR_PNT_NO = snap.BTLR_DLVR_PNT_NO 
                                                   AND invcorp.OWNRSHP_ID = snap.OWNRSHP_ID 
            INNER JOIN
                sys_calendar.calendar cal ON invcorp.inv_dt = cal.calendar_date
            WHERE 
                1 = 1 
                AND invcorp.inv_dt = dVAR;
    END;    

    SET dVAR = (CAST(dVAR AS DATE) - 7);
    SET iVAR = (iVAR-1);

END WHILE;  
END;
```

Comment: The stored procedure is being executed with the privileges of the owner and the user calling the stores procedure. The owner of the stored procedure would next SELECT WITH GRANT OPTION granted on the referenced objects or the stored procedure has to be recompiled with a different option for privileges used during execution.

Comment: Don't know about the permissions error, but why are you using a loop?  Looks to me like you should be able to use a between - `inv_dt between (select week_of_calendar from sys_calendar.calendar where calendar_date = current_date) and (select week_of_calendar - 52 from sys_calendar.calendar where calendar_date = current_date)`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little long in the tooth, but thanks to a recent edit, it's popped back up to the top of the queue:

With procedures there are three "roles" under which security can be assigned (actually 4 but I'll get to that)

1. OWNER - This is the database/user under which the procedure is being created. If you are using default SQL SECURITY settings for the procedure than `OWNER` will need to have access to the objects being used in the procedure `WITH GRANT OPTION`. So: `GRANT SELECT ON corp_invoice_VIEWS TO <whatever database this proc is in> WITH GRANT OPTION` you will need to grant that access for each database/view/table that is being selected here in the `FROM` clause.
2. CREATOR - This is you since you are compiling the procedure. With default SQL SECURITY settings for the procedure you will need to have access to the objects used in the procedure. You must have that access already in order to run the SELECT by itself. So this is all good.
3. INVOKER - This is the user that will execute/call the procedure. With default SQL SECURITY Settings for the procedure the `INVOKER` merely needs to have `EXECUTE` procedure to the procedure.

The default SQL SECURITY settings on a procedure (Which can be overridden when writing the procedure) is `SQL SECURITY DEFINER`. This is the "4th" role I mentioned above. Definer security checks that both the `CREATOR` and `OWNER` of the procedure have access to the objects in the procedure when the procedure is compiled. Furthermore when the procedure is executed `OWNER` privileges are checked once again. It throws an error at the time of compile if you and the database in which this procedure resides doesn't have access. It will throw an error at execution time if the `OWNER` (database in which the procedure resides) doesn't have access as well.

Your options to get around this error:

1. Grant the owner of the procedure SELECT access to the tables, views, or databases containing those tables/views WITH GRANT OPTION so that the SQL SECURITY DEFINER default is satisfied. This is the more secure and less volatile route.
2. Change the sql security on the procedure to SQL SECURITY CREATOR so that only your credentials (the creator of the procedure) are checked at compile and execution. This is a cheap fix, but understandable if you lack permissions to change security for the database you are working in.
3. Change the sql security on the procedure to SQL SECURITY INVOKER so that only the person executing the procedure after it's compiled is used for checking privileges. This means that the user executing will not only have to have EXECUTE PROCEDURE access to the procedure but will need to have SELECT access to the views/tables used within. This is probably a safer option than number 2, but less robust then option 1 (where creator and owner are checked).

You can read more about the procedure security [at the documentation site](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/eWpPpcMoLGQcZEoyt5AjEg/sTc_IhlTt_NTBjP4h5fh_g).